# Changing a cell value in a columns based on a query from two other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a DataFrame with four columns: "date", "time_gap", "count" and "average_speed".

I'd like to set values to the count column when requirements are met based on the "date" and "time_gap" columns.

So, for example, if I'm running this query:

```
random_row = df.query("date == '2018-12-07' & time_gap == 86")
```

It's returning this as output:

```
      date         time_gap   count   average_speed
282   2018-12-07   86         0       0
```

Let's say I want to change the value in the count columns with 12, how could I do it?

I've tried this:

```
random_row = df.query("date == '2018-12-07' & time_gap == 86")["count"].replace(0, 12)
```

Which returns this:

```
282    12
Name: count, dtype: int64
```

But when I'm having a look at the df:

```
df.iloc[282]
```

I still have my row where the "count" is equal to 0:

```
date             2018-12-07 00:00:00
time_gap                          86
count                              0
average_speed                      0
Name: 282, dtype: object
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with `loc`, if you don't want to use NumPy:

```
df.loc[ (df.date.eq('07/12/2018')) & (df.time_gap.eq(86)), 'count' ] = 12
```

prints:

```
         date  time_gap  count  average_speed
0  07/12/201
8        86     12              0
```

Yes, but in order to do that you have to use `eval`, which takes the expression passed in `query`, and evaluates it:

```
qr = "date == '07/12/2018' & time_gap == 86"
df.loc[df.eval(qr), 'count'] = 12
```

prints:

```
         date  time_gap  count  average_speed
0  07/12/2018        86     12              0
```

You can see practical applications of `eval` [here](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/built-in/eval).

Comment: It's working, thanks a lot :)
Out of curiosity, is there a way to do it with query()?

Comment: Updated the answer. Yes you can.

Comment: Thank you, but it's still using .loc which I believe could be replace by the .query() method: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html
As mentioned, my question was purely out of curiosity and your solution works perfectly. But when I'm trying to do something similar with the query method: df.query("date == '2018-12-07' & time_gap == 86", "count") = 12, it's not working for example

Answer (score 1):

Use np.where:

```
import numpy as np
df["count"] = np.where((df["date"] == '2018-12-07') & (df["time_gap" == 86), 0, df["count"])
```

Answer (score 1):

using the pd.loc to identify the row to update and the updating the column with the desire value

```
df.loc[(df['date'] == '2018-12-07' )  & (df['time_gap'] == 86) , 'count'] = 12
df
```

Comment: An explanation would be in order. E.g., what is the idea/gist? From [the Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/promotion): *"...always explain why the solution you're presenting is appropriate and how it works"*. Please respond by [editing (changing) your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73224914/edit), not here in comments (***without*** "Edit:", "Update:", or similar - the answer should appear as if it was written today).

Comment: @PeterMortensen , added the explanation. I assumed it to have been straight forward, so didn't add explanation

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
df["count"] [(df["date"] == '2018-12-07') & (df["time_gap"] == 86)] = 12
```

It was basically what you were doing, but using the square brackets to filter instead of using a query.